# Projectile Motion

Tags: integration

How would I go about solving for the velocity $V$ and the angle $\theta$ required to clear the two buildings?

### EDIT:

The distance from (0,0) to the first tower is 16m, and the distance from the first to the second tower is 16m also.

Here is a diagram:
http://puu.sh/k3YBI/4a24d518ee.png

I can do a similar problem if there is one object in the way, but when there's two, I'm not sure what to do.

### Method I used:

I started with,

$
x'' = -gj
$

Then integrated to obtain,

$
x'(t) = -gtj + ci + dj
$

Then used the initial conditions to arrive at,

$
x'(0) = Vcos(\theta)i + Vsin(\theta)j
$

I then compared the two to obtain a general expression,

$
x'(0) = Vcos(\theta)i + Vsin(\theta)j = x'(t) = -gtj + ci + dj
$

Resulting in,

$
x'(t) = Vcos(\theta)i + (Vsin(\theta)-gt)j 
$

etc.

I then arrive at,

$
x'(t) = Vcost(\theta)i + (Vsint(\theta)-\dfrac{gt^2}{2})j 
$

For a typical one object question I just rearrange the two expressions, find an expression for $V^2$ in terms of $sin(\theta)$ and  $cos(\theta)$. After that I graph the expression's denominator and find local maximums for the velocity $V$ and the angle $\theta$.

Comment: There is a mistake in diagram.Provide the x coordinates of the obstacles or the distance between them.

Comment: @Sanchayan Dutta - The question has been edited.

Comment: Why don't you go to physics stack exchange for this? Just write down the trajectory $y= -\frac{gx^2}{2v^2 \cos ^2 \theta} +x \tan \theta$, and require $y(16)>7.1$ and $y(32)>4.4$. You will get a condition for $v$ and $\theta$

Comment: Physics stack exchange doesn't welcome homework problems

Answer (score 0):

[image: Equation of trajectory]

I framed two equations

$7.1=16tan Ө-\frac{g(16)^2}{2(v cos  Ө)^2}$-------------(1)

$4.4=32tan Ө-\frac{g(32)^2}{2(v cos  Ө)^2}$--------------(2)

$4*(1)-(2)$ gives

$tan Ө=3/4$ so Ө=36 degrees approx

Solve for u by placing the value of Ө in (1).
Done!